# Catching SIGINT signal to terminate a custom shell

Tags: c, signals, system-calls

Hope you can help me to resolve this problem.

For school I have to transform <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to a command which doesn't shut down the shell, but he reminds through `printf()` that I must type exit to close the shell. I don't even know where to start.

Thank a lot.

Comment: This depends very much on your operating system. For POSIX systems (like e.g. Linux or OSX) do a search for *SIGINT*, on Windows do a search for *SetConsoleCtrlHandler*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `signal()`+`SIGINT` also works on Windows. Except for GUI applications.

Comment: You would have found the answer much faster if you searched it on google.

Comment: would I? :D what should i had looked up?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a trivial implementation of handling `SIGINT` using [`sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) which will work on posix systems. Left out error checking for brevity. The linked manual should explain about `sigaction`.

Basically the program loops through an infinite loop and break if user types exit. Using `write` as you can't use printf in signal handler. See [`signal manual`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for a list of functions that can be used safely in a signal handler.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char s[]="Type 'exit' to terminate\n";

void int_handler (int signum)
{
  write(fileno(stdin), s, sizeof s - 1);
}

int main (void)
{
  char str[256];
  struct sigaction sh;

  sh.sa_handler = int_handler;
  sigemptyset (&sh.sa_mask);
  sh.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction (SIGINT, &sh, NULL);
  printf("%s", s);

  while(1) {
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
    if(p) *p = 0;
    if(!strcmp(str, "exit")) {
      printf("Exiting on request...");
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there an easier way to reach the same goal?

Comment: What I posted is a naive implementation of catching SIGINT. There's no *easier* way! Just read about how signals works in the linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+C sends an interrupt signal (SIGINT) to the running process.You can use signal() to catch SIGINT like this:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<signal.h>

 void sigint_handler(int sig)
 {
   printf("Type exit to close the shell!\n");
 }


  int main()
  {
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

    /*Your code should replace the while loop.*/
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Running!\n");
        getchar();
    }

    return 0 ;
  }
```

Comment: Tha [POSIX manual for signal()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) says "*... new applications should use [sigaction()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) rather than signal().*"

Comment: And there are severe restrictions on what you can do in a signal handler invoked asynchronously like this. Quote from the standard: "[T]he behavior is undefined if [...] the signal handler calls any function in the standard library other than the abort function, the _Exit function, or the signal function with the first argument equal to the signal number corresponding to the signal that caused the invocation of the handler."

Answer (score 0):

As you're talking about doing it from the shell, you probably want:

```
$ trap "echo Please type \'exit\' to close the shell." SIGINT
<Ctrl-C>
Please type 'exit' to close the shell.
$
```

This specifies a command to execute when the listed signal is trapped (the `trap` command can also trap other signals; SIGINT is the one generated by `Ctrl-C`).  The `\'` protects the quote from being interpreted by the shell.

Comment: @Pino, evidently, then, the shell to which you refer is one you are *writing yourself*, yes?  The program that receives an interrupt signal (as a result of the user typing a Ctrl-C) must provide its own handler, one way or another, if it is to produce a non-default response.

Comment: Sorry, I took "shut down the shell" to mean the interactive one.