# Custom SIGINT signal handler - Program still terminates even after signal is caught

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix

I am playing with the `signal.h` and `unistd.h` libraries, and I am having some issues. In the code below, when I send the `SIGINT` signal to my running program by calling `CTRL-C`, the signal is caught. However, when pressing `CTRL-C` again, the program terminates. As I understand it, the print statement `"Received signal 2"` should be printed every time I press `CTRL-C`.

Is my understanding of this signal incorrect, or is there a bug in my code?

Thanks for your input!

```
#include "handle_signals.h"


void sig_handler(int signum)
{
    printf("\nReceived signal %d\n", signum);
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal output:

```
xxx@ubuntu:~/Dropbox/xxx/handle_signals$ ./handle_signals 
^C
Received signal 2
^C
xxx@ubuntu:~/Dropbox/xxx/handle_signals$
```

Edit: Here is the header I've included

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void sig_handler(int signum);
```

Thanks for your responses. Reading through them now!

Comment: you don't "send ctrl+c", you press that. What happens then is that the keypress is interpreted in a way that sends SIGINT to your process. There's no guarantee that your shell doesn't think "Hm, two ctrl+c in a row, better send SIGKILL" or something. Try using `killall -SIGINT yourprogram` and have a look if it works better.

Comment: It works fine on my system. What is in your file `handle_signals.h`?  Also note, that strictly speaking, the signal handler shall not invoke other system function like `printf`, it shall just set some flag variables or so.

Comment: @Marian: not only strictly speaking, it's never a good idea to do much IO in signal handlers. However, `printf` is not a system function (it's a libc function), but it's a function that internally calls `write` and maybe `fdatasync`. For reference on the system calls allowed, run `man 7 signal`; `write` and `fdatasync` are allowed inside signal handlers. Which doesn't mean it's a good idea -- a signal might basically happen everywhere in execution, even when there's just about stuff to be flushed to stdout, so you get a nice mixture of signal handler and regular output.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ: actually there is a guarantee that the shell won't do that: the shell doesn't even see the Ctrl+C (it's all handled by the terminal driver code in the kernel).

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ `printf(3)` is not async-signal safe. It may call `malloc(3)` or `free(3)` for various reasons - for example, to initialize buffers internally used by the standard I/O library. It shouldn't be used inside a signal handler.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: you're right. I'm so often wrong these days!

Comment: @psmears: What is the significance that the shell does not even see CTRL+C?

Comment: @newbie: Marcus had metnioned that the shell might think "two Ctrl+Cs in a row, I'll send SIGKILL" - but in fact that can't happen, because the signal is not sent by the shell - and it couldn't if it wanted to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `signal`, use `sigaction`:

> The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux. **Avoid its use:** use    sigaction(2) instead.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html

> In the original UNIX systems, when a handler that was established using signal() was invoked by the delivery of a signal, the disposition of the signal would be reset to SIG_DFL, and the system did not block delivery of further instances of the signal.

Linux implements the same semantics: the handler is reset when the signal is delivered.

Comment: I have tried using sigaction successfully. However, I keep getting an implicit declaration warning for sigaction no matter what I include. I'll keep using sigaction, but in the back of my mind it keeps bothering me. Do you know why this warning keeps occurring?

Comment: That's weird, according to the man page you only need `signal.h`. Maybe post another question with the detailed message & compiler and OS versions?

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of `signal` upon receiving the first signal varies on different implementation. Typically, it requires reinstalling the handler after receiving the signal as handler is reset to its default action:

```
void sig_handler(int signum)
{  
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
    printf("\nReceived signal %d\n", signum);
}
```

which is one of the reasons you shouldn't use `signal` anymore and use [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html). You can see a bare bone example of [using sigaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31076034/1275169) here.

Comment: Confirmed this worked. Good to know this! I will check out sigaction now.