# Terminating client threads in a client-server setup using pthreads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a made a simple chat-server program which uses multiple threads for processing multiple clients. Once I start my server, many client would be connecting to the server and hence multiple threads will be created. Now, at some time I close the server.

Will all the threads which were created be destroyed? How can I check if any of the threads are alive or dead? I am working on Linux platform.

Server.c:

```
    //for running type ./a.out anyportnumber
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
int s2;
int arr[100];
int tc = 0;
int flag = 1;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void handler(int signal)
{
    flag = 0;
}
void sendtoall(char *msg,int s1)
{
    int i;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    for(i = 0; i < tc; i++) {
        if(arr[i] != s1) 
            write(arr[i],msg,strlen(msg));
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
void *function(void *s)
{
    int s1;
    int n;
    char rmsg[500];
    s1 = *(int *)s;
    while((n = read(s1,rmsg,500)) > 0) {
        if(flag == 0) {
            break;
        }
        rmsg[n] = '\0';
        sendtoall(rmsg,s1);
        bzero(rmsg,500);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int arrc,char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    int s1,len;
    int n;
    int port;
    pthread_t t1;
    char message[500];
    port = atoi(argv[1]);
    bzero((char *)&server,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(s1 == -1) {
        perror("socket not created\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(bind(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        perror("socket not binded\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(listen(s1,5) == -1) {
        perror("unable to listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    while(1) {
        if(flag == 0) {
            break;
        }
        s2 = accept(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&len);
        pthread_create(&t1,NULL,function,(void *)&s2);
        arr[tc] = s2;
        tc++;
    }
    close(s1);
    close(s2);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: hard to know if you don't post any code. Can you?

Comment: and how do you "close the server"?

Comment: By pressing ctrl + c in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes: when the main process exits, all threads will die too.

But in your code, I don't see any "closing" of the server. You are just creating threads in an infinite loop with many issues in the code:

- Not checking if threads creation was successful.
- May overrun the array `arr` (which can only handle 100 elements).
- Joining only with the very last created, which is in fact an unreachable statement.
- Accessing `rmsg[n] = '\0';` which is a potential candidate for UB. If `read(2)` reads 500 chars, then `n` will be `500` and `rmsg[n] = '\0';` is out-of-bounds access.

Comment: and once all that is fixed, perhaps a good solution for what I think OP originally wanted could be to catch SIGINT in the main thread, set some global var and use that to break out of while loop, and wait for ALL threads to finish.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to kill a thread when a client disconnects from server? How do I know if a client has disconnected?

Comment: @ShivamMitra Since you create a thread for each client and call `pthread_exit(0)`, the thread will terminate. You don't need to "kill" explicitly. One suggestion is to use `pthread_detach(pthread_self());` in the thread function so that the thread specific data structure is cleaned up when it dies. Your main problem is to devise a strategy to close the server (that loop). You can catch SIGINT if you want ctrl+c as the closing machanism. Or you can let the server handle a fixed number of clients and if it's exceed then wait until some clients close.

Comment: @ShivamMitra Here's a [simple example I wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31076034/1275169) to catch `SIGINT` (which is what generated for <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> on Linux). But as said before, your should decide whether the server needs to handle as many requests as it possibly can or only a fixed number of clients and rewrite your code accordingly.

Comment: I will implement it. But I have a question. Once I press ctrl+c, the process will anyway be terminated. So what is the use SIGINT?

Comment: @ShivamMitra SIGINT is the signal generated when you press ctrl+C on the terminal, which is sent to the process and by defaut, it kills the process. By catching this signal, your program what to do when user presses ctrl+C.

Comment: @I3x I have implemented a function to catch SIGINT but my program doesn't terminate. I have posted the code.

Comment: @ShivamMitra Please post a new question if you have more questions instead of editing the same post. Use `volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 1;` instead of `int`.